# Import Access 2013 Table Into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, import, sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access-2013

I do not see the upsizing wizard in my Access 2013 install, and anytime I right click on my database and say tasks then import data, if I click either of the access options it is only searching for .mdb extension not the .accdb extension.

What do I have to do in order to import an access 2013 table into SQL Server 2008?

**EDIT**
1)  And there is no linked server between my server and access (I am not a sys admin to add) so using the `Openrowset` is not an option

2) I have the Access 2007 Database Engine installed on my system already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of options:
1. Use "SQL Server Import and Export"
2. Use SSIS to transfer the data.
3. Create table in SQL, link that table in Access and run a table population query there.

Probably there can be other options.

Comment: My issue is the Import/Export does not show an .accdb format.  Option 1 or 3 are an option, thank you for that.

Comment: I believe you can create ODBC connection, which will be recognizable by SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

Access 2010 was the last version of Access to include the "upsizing wizard" for SQL Server. For Access 2013 and later the recommended approach is to use the

[SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (AccessToSQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313039(v=sql.110).aspx)